# Does there exist a Google Docs-like site for social programming?

Tags: python, collaboration

My lead coder and I want to hack a quick python program together tomorrow. Is there a site that will allow us, like Google Docs, to work on a program at the same time and run the code?

Comment: @weezybizzle it would be a sort of collaborative ideone.com ... awesome.

Comment: we call that github + skype where i'm from...

Comment: @Triptych not efficient enough :-/

Comment: I once used http://collabedit.com/ during an interview, which worked really well.

Comment: Great question, but not directly related to programming. Perhaps /programmers ?

Answer (score 5):

I have recently started using [PythonAnywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com/).  It lets you start a console on your account, and share it with others.  The site is currently in limited-beta, but I got an invite just a few hours after my request.  When you share a console, the friend doesn't need an account.

Comment: for info, PythonAnywhere is now out of private beta, and anyone can sign up to check it out...

Answer (score 1):

I think [Cloud 9](http://c9.io/) will do what you want, but it's not free unless you're open source.

Answer (score 0):

[Github](http://github.com)?

It's not quite the same (not instant), but works well.

Answer (score 0):

There is such functionality at [rextester](http://rextester.com/runcode).

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users, there is a collaborative editor that should work for hacking together some Python. http://www.codingmonkeys.de/subethaedit/

Also, google turned up http://gobby.0x539.de/trac/ but I've never tried that.

Of course, each of you editing the script will still have to run it locally. ;)